# How to compare two hive table records

Tags: mysql, hiveql

I have two tables Core and BKP. Table BKP contains data with duplicates.But Core contains the same data without duplicates.

primary key for two tables is combination of 4 fields(1,2,3,4).

But after running some script some records from Core table missed.

How can I find out missed records from Core table,(the missed records definitely there in BKP but having duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NOT EXISTS:

```
Select b.PK1,b.PK2,b.PK3,b.PK4 --Primary key from BKP missed in CORE
 from 
(--select all PK existing in BKP
  select 
      distinct
      b.PK1,b.PK2,b.PK3,b.PK4 --Primary key from BKP
  from BKP b) b
where not exists(select 1 from CORE c 
                  where c.PK1=b.PK1 
                    and c.PK2=b.PK2
                    and c.PK3=b.PK3
                    and c.PK4=b.PK4
                )
```

Using LEFT JOIN:

```
    Select b.PK1,b.PK2,b.PK3,b.PK4 --Primary key from BKP missed in CORE
     from 
    (--select all PK existing in BKP
      select 
          distinct
          b.PK1,b.PK2,b.PK3,b.PK4 --Primary key from BKP
      from BKP b
    ) b
     left join 
               (select c.PK1,c.PK2,c.PK3,c.PK4 --Primary key from CORE
                  from CORE c 
                ) c 
           on c.PK1=b.PK1 
              and c.PK2=b.PK2
              and c.PK3=b.PK3
              and c.PK4=b.PK4
  where c.PK1 is null --absent in CORE
```